# Android: Set selected icon in GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, gallery, imageview

I'm trying to find a way to store the name of an icon in my database, then use that name to let a user select an icon from an ImageView. I've found various guides on ImageViews and Galleries, but none that show how to get/set the selected image by name. The list of available images won't change, but what's that best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

check this tutorial, it can give you an Idea of how to do it:

http://www.firstdroid.com/2011/02/06/android-tutorial-gridview-with-icon-and-text/

Good luck.
Adrian.

Comment: The link is not available now